# inputrc windows for ipdb kybinding

Tags: python, vi, inputrc

I am trying to get vi bindings for python debugger ipdb. I am not running cygwin's python but the windows version from the dos command prompt. I have tried creating `.inputrc` in my `%HOMEPATH%` directory, but the binding

Answer (score 0):

2 missing pieces helped me solve this:

1. interactive shell for `ipdb` on Windows is managed by `pyreadline`
2. `pyreadline` options are determined by `pyreadlineconfig.ini`

Solution:

1. Copy `pyreadlineconfig.ini` from `<python-install>\Lib\site-packages\pyreadline\configuration` to `%HOMEPATH%`
2. Uncomment `set_mode("vi")` line at end of file